# How to count numbers that contain specific digits

Tags: combinatorics

What is the best way to count the numbers between $0$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ that contain  at least one occurrence (and possibly several occurrences) of specific digits (base $10$) in the set $\{d_1, d_2, ... d_n\}$ where $1\leq n \leq \lfloor \log_{10}(N) \rfloor + 1$?

For example, we are looking for the count of numbers between $1$ and $1000000$ that contain $3,5$ and $7$ at least once each. In this case, $357$ should be counted, as well as $753$, $735$, $357894$, but also $335577, 333571, \ldots$. The order in which $3,5$ and $7$ appear does not matter. On the other hand, $3, 37, 35, 35878, 73468 \ldots$ should not be counted, as they do not contain at least $1$ occurrence of each of $3$, $5$ and $7$.

Comment: In all your examples, 3 appears before 5 which appears before 7.  That is just a coincidence and NOT a requirement, right?  I.e. you also want to count 753, right?  If my interpretation is correct, then it might be easier to count the complement (which can be counted using inclusion-exclusion, I think).

Comment: @antkam - yes, it is a coincidence, order does not matter here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't consider them numbers, but 6 digit strings, including 0.

And w.l.o.g., consider the digits that should occur $A$, $B$, $C$, and they can be used arbitrarily.

Then I would use in/exclusion from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle  to calculate the number.

The principle is more clearly seen in the case of three sets, which for the sets A, B and C is given by

$ |A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|.$

Where:

1. $|A| = |B| = |C| = 10^6-9^6$, cardinality of sequences contains at least one $A$ = everything except the sequences that do not contain $A$ (consist of the other $9$ symbols.)
2. $|A \cup B | = |A \cup C | = |B \cup C | = 10^6-8^6 $ (used for 3.), cardinality of sequences containing at least one $A$ or $B$.
3. $|A \cap B | = |A \cap C | = |B \cap C | = |A|+|B|-|A\cup B| = 10^6 - 9^6 - 9^6 + 8^6$
4. $|A \cup B \cup C | = 10^6-7^6 $

Be careful with all the signs, and you come up with something like: 
$$ 10^6-3 \cdot 9^6+3  \cdot 8^6-7^6 = 74460 $$

Comment: Can you give more details for 3. and 4.? Can you also remove "probably" from the last sentence :-) Actually, all 1, 2, 3 and 4, IMHO deserve some details. I'm assuming |A| stands for the cardinal of the set of numbers that contain digit A exactly once, or at least once? Similarly, what exactly is $A\cap B$? $A\cup B$? Just want to make the definitions are precise enough, otherwise it's hard to really understand the counting.

Comment: @Frank, I think there even was an error in 3. Since half of the operations take place in complements, it is quite tedious. (Hence the probably, careful, signs remark.)

Comment: Pieter21 - The details you added are great, they make it easy to follow the counting. I selected this as the answer for this question since IMHO working with the formula for inclusion/exclusion and complements is easier than Christian's solution - which is also a great answer in any case. I also verified the answer separately via a counting program, and it checks out.

Answer (score 2):

We are searching among the $10^6$ strings $000000$–$999999$.

We begin by setting up a list of the possible frequencies of the special digits $3$, $5$, $7$. These are three positive frequencies adding up to $\leq6$. A case search shows that there are the following $7$ types:
$$411,\quad 321,\quad 311,\quad 222,\quad 221,\quad 211,\quad 111\ .$$
We now determine for each type $ijk$ the number $N_{ijk}$ of possible strings of length $6$, whereby the nonused slots are filled with arbitrary digits from $0$, $1$,$2$,$4$,$6$,$8$,$9$.

For $411$ we can choose the special digit appearing four times in $3$ ways and place it four times in ${6\choose4}$ ways. The two remaining special digits can then be placed in $2$ ways. Hence $N_{411}=3\cdot{6\choose4}\cdot2=90$.

For $321$ we can choose the special digit appearing three times in $3$ ways and place it three times in ${6\choose3}$ ways. We then can choose the special digit appearing only once in $2$ ways and place it in $3$ ways. Hence $N_{321}=3\cdot{6\choose3}\cdot2\cdot3=360$.

Similarly $N_{311}=3\cdot{6\choose3}\cdot3\cdot2\cdot 7=2520$, whereby the factor $7$ comes from choosing the digit for the not yet used slot.

Etcetera.

Comment: This is a good answer, but IMHO Pieter21's answer is superior, because it requires less work.

Comment: It's interesting that this method is certainly correct, but tedious, which is evidenced by the fact that it ends in "et cetera" :-)

Comment: It can be argued with that the other method is easier. To be precise, we can most likely argue against the existence of an easy counting method to this problem in general.

Comment: @Sudix - hmmm - inclusion/exclusion is the ticket to write a general formula to count for this problem though. If you look at the last line of Pieter21, you can immediately see the parameters of the problem. It looks like a general formula could be found that way.

Comment: @Frank The problem there is, if you look at the general inclusion-exclusion formula, the sum(s) appearing there:$$\begin{align*}
|A| = |A_1\cup ...\cup A_n| =&
 \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} \sum_{1\leq i_1 <...<i_k\leq n} |A_{i_1} \cap ... \cap A_{i_k}| \\
=& \sum_{k=1}^n \bigg( (-1)^{k+1} 
\sum_{\substack{I\subseteq \{1,...,n\}\\{|I|= k}}}
\,\,\,\big|\,\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i}\big|\bigg) 
\end{align*}$$ This is the general formula for inclusion-exclusion if you have $n$ different digits you care about. The sum has $2^n$ summands, which you'll  have to calculate.